# When using the acronym package and the smaller option, how to avoid the tiny 's' in the plural acronym?

Tags: typography, acronyms

I'm using the acronym package, and using the smaller option because that is a typographic convention.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[smaller]{acronym}
\acrodef{DLL}{Dynamically Linked Library}
\begin{document}
The plural of \ac{DLL} is \acp{DLL} but that `s' just looks way too tiny.
\end{document}
```

Compiled with pdflatex:
[image: PDF result]

But the plural form of the acronym (`\acp`) appends an s but this is much to small in my opinion, and looks off.

Should I try to fix this or this typographically accepted? I was thinking about a new command `\DLLs` (and `\DLL`) which added a normal 's' but that just feels dirty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the answer to this question: [Plurals](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/CMS_FAQ/Plurals/Plurals11.html) (from *The Chicago Manual of Style Online*), an acronym should be treated as a word with its own meaning, so (extrapolating) the "s" indicating plural should have the size of the lower-case "s" corresponding to the font size of the acronym.

Invoking the `smaller` option for the acronym package results in typesetting the acronym using `\textsmaller` from the `relsize` package. The "s" indicating the plural form will have the size of the lower-case "s" with `\textsmaller`, so I think that the right option would be to leave the size of the "s" as it is. Furthermore, increasing the size for the "s" could result in confusion if the size of the "s" is too close to the size of the singular form of the acronym.

However, if you *really* want to change the size of the "s" indicating plural forms , you need to redefine the internal commands `\AC@aclp`, and `\AC@acsp`. The simplest way to achieve this is to patch those commands through the `etoolbox` package. A little example, in which the "s" will have size given by `\normalsize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[smaller]{acronym}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\AC@aclp}{\AC@acl{#1}s}{\AC@acl{#1}{\normalsize s}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\AC@acsp}{\AC@acs{#1}s}{\AC@acs{#1}{\normalsize s}}{}{}
\makeatother

\acrodef{DLL}{Dynamically Linked Library}

\begin{document}
The plural of \ac{DLL} is \acp{DLL}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: okay, I added the typographical part of the question, it was a bit implicit. but thanks for your solution.

Comment: @Davy Landman: I updated my answer with a note on the typocraphical aspect.